# How to have a smart pointer to a view object get ownership of the underlying buffer object?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Let's say I have an underlying buffer

```
char *c = new char[100];
```

which I reference through a View object (which does not take ownership, but offers the actual functionality)

```
View *v = new View(c);
```

Now I would like to construct a smart pointer, such that when dereferenced gives the `View* v` object, but when destroyed destroys both the `View* v` and `char* c` objects. Something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<View, my_deleter> p(v,my_deleter(c));
```

such that `*p` gives `*v` instance but when deleted `my_deleter` actually destroys both `v` and `c`.

In case you want to see an actual use case for this functionality, consider a function `get_image()` obtaining an image from a hardware camera, which must return an Eigen object for further processing. `Eigen::Map` is a suitable object (which acts as a View object) because no copy of the underlying driver buffer is needed. Nevertheless I must also return a reference to the original buffer object, because it must eventually be destroyed. This forces the receiving party to ensure deallocation eventually happens, at code that may know nothing about the camera implementation and its buffer objects. Returning a smart pointer to `Eigen::Map` which eventually deallocates the buffer object is desirable.

Comment: Tricky. Unless the view has a backchannel to the true owner of the resource, taking ownership of the resource through the view will leave you with two objects believing that they own the resource.

Comment: @user4581301 The buffer object is a pointer (like for example `char *c = new char[100];` ). It won't be deleted until `delete` is explicitly invoked on it. If for example the buffer object is allocated inside a function, it will go out of scope and loose one of the "owners".

Comment: That pretty much means there is no initial owner, just a raw pointer to the resource. In that case You don't have to worry about what I was concerned with, but you do have to make certain that ownership is taken by someone along the line or you've got a leak.

Comment: @user4581301 Correct. One way to achieve that is to return a View and a smart pointer which holds the buffer object. But then the receiver is in charge to not delete the smart pointer until done using the View. I'd rather return a smart pointer with the functionality described in the question

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading the question again to see what I missed the first time to completely misunderstand the question.

Comment: Have you considered `shared_ptr` and using a `weak_ptr` acquired from the `shared_ptr` as the view? Just outright nuking the view while someone could be using it is gauche. Deleters in `shared_ptr`s are a bit more versatile as well.

Comment: @user4581301 You mean modify the view so that it contains a `weak_ptr` instead of the pointer it probably has? I do not usually own the View code. In my particular use case the View is either Eigen `Matrix` or OpenCV `Mat`, both of which provide a method to act as a view of an existing raw buffer.

Comment: I was thinking more use the `weak_ptr` as the view, but if you don't necessarily control the view, that's off the table. I'm having trouble with reading comprehension today . Maybe it's the heat.

Comment: @user4581301 Your brainstorming is useful to me, to also boost my own brainstorming :)

Comment: Is the resource, view, etc... all created, used, and disposed-of in the same thread?

Comment: @user4581301 Most probably in the same thread, yes. How would that help?

Comment: It sounds like you want a `std::shared_ptr` to your buffer and a `unique_ptr` to your `View`.

Comment: Fewer things to go wrong if you don't have to worry about thread B using the view at the same time as thread A deletes it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    A* pa = new A();
    auto deleter = [pa](B* pb) { delete pa; delete pb; };
    std::unique_ptr<B, decltype(deleter)> pb(new B(), deleter);
}
```

Comment: This is great. I do not know what magic allows this, but I just discovered you can use `shared_ptr<B> pb(new B(), deleter);` without having `decltype(deleter)` in the smart pointer type, and still get it deleted through the custom deleter. This way the receiver doesnt need to know you are doing this magic.

Comment: See fully templated example here: https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F%2F+Example+program%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++std%3A%3Astring+name%3B%0A++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22What+is+your+name%3F+%22%3B%0A++getline+(std%3A%3Acin%2C+name)%3B%0A++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Hello%2C+%22+%3C%3C+name+%3C%3C+%22!%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D

Comment: @AndresR Probably you wanted to paste a different link.

Comment: Correct link: See fully templated example here:  tinyurl.com/y7hm4jn8